# Configure CloudWatch Logs to record whitespace?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Is it possible to configure CloudWatch Logs to keep whitespace?

I have a script that nicely formats its output, using ample whitespace to make it easy to visually parse.
However, when I run it on EC2 and record its logs using CloudWatch, none of the whitespace prints are recorded as events, and it appears many (all?) other events have their whitespace stripped from the beginning and end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
If you're using `ecs-cli` with the Docker Compose syntax config file (a `docker-compose.yml`), the the trick is to set `awslogs-multiline-pattern` to `‘^[^\s]'`.

Here's an example:

```
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: mygroup
        awslogs-create-group: "true"
        awslogs-region: myregion
        awslogs-stream-prefix: myprefix
        awslogs-multiline-pattern: ‘^[^\s]'
```

For me, if I now concat the logs I see exactly what I would have seen if I'd just run my binaries locally on the command line.

`awslogs-multiline-pattern` probably corresponds to `multi_line_start_pattern` [described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html).
However, this documentation claims the default value for `multi_line_start_pattern` is `‘^[^\s]'`, which is apparently not the case when using `ecs-cli` with Docker Compose syntax.